# MySQLdb import fails on OSX 10.8.2

Tags: python, django

I have installed MySQL-python via pip , but I still cannot import MySQLdb , any ideas what the issue could be?

```
pip install MySQL-python
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MySQL-python in /usr/local    /lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...



>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the module from Python 2.7?

Comment: yes, definitly python 2.7, although I am wondering if I multiple versions somehow though, as I had python installed, then installed a new version with brew

Comment: Run `which pip` and see what you get. You might be installing the module to the OS X Python's `site-packages`, but you're running the Brew Python install.

Comment: yes , this was it, pip and python were going to two seperate directories /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a GREAT opportunity to shift to using virtualenv (virtualenvwrapper).  Once you go there you will NEVER go back and better you will not see these rookie errors in the future!.

Please step back and take the necessary time to get familiar with pip.  Here are some great resources.

- http://jontourage.com/2011/02/09/virtualenv-pip-basics/
- http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/